# Can I embed BVH player into a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, 3d, mobile-development

Is it possible to embed a BVH player in a Flutter application? I know it is kind of a vague question, but I would like to know any connection I can create between the BVH player and my Flutter application. I know it is possible to add a Unity widget to the Flutter application, but how can I utilize it to achieve this particular task?